# How to amplify a 25khz square wave that goes from -3.3v to +3.3v so that the amplitude is doubled

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, waveform, transducer, square

I have a 3.3v power supply (lithium ion battery) and am using a TI MPS430G2553 chip to generate a 25khz square wave using 2 PWM pins and a push-pull setup.  This square wave goes from -3.3v to +3.3v.  I need it to produce at least double that voltage (-6.6v to +6.6v) without messing up the 25khz square wave.  I will be programatically changing the frequency of this wave from time to time, but will keep it within 1khz of 25khz.

The above circuit is driving a 25khz Piezo Transducer which has a capacitance of 2500pf.  The current setup is producing about 80dB.  I need 115dB.  The datasheet on the Piezo says that at 10v (I'm assuming peak to peak), it will produce 115dB.  So if I could double the voltage of the above circuit while maintaining the square wave, I believe I could accomplish my goal.

I have no additional power supply and would like to accomplish this with as few components as possible, for as low cost as possible.

Any recommendations with a circuit example would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: An [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/241123/32787) to your previous question suggested a transformer with a bridge-driver. You should probably research battery-powered, low-voltage bridges and signal transformers.

Comment: A circuit diagram of your existing push-pull driver would help us.

Comment: There's no circuit.  I attach a the 2 terminals from my Piezo Transducer to 2 of the PWM pins on the MSP430G2553 chip.  I should probably add a resister between the Piezo and the chip, but don't currently have one.  Recommendations are welcome.  I'm a software guy, not hardware.  I can follow a schematic and assemble a circuit, but I am clueless as to its innerworkings.

Comment: If you are just driving it directly from a MSP430, how are you currently getting it to go down to -3.3V?

Comment: Is it really 2200 nF and not 2200 pF? So what is wrong about the previous answers?

Comment: You're likely going to have to give up some of your requirements. You could use a transformer (and avoid adding a power supply), but that would likely distort the square wave and maybe overload the uC's drive capability. Or you can add another power supply (maybe +15 V) and use an op-amp circuit to amplify the signal with minimal distortion.

Comment: You can use a half-bridge to drive the piezo to toggle between +10V and GND to get 10V peak-to-peak. Drive this half-bridge with an NPN with output pullup resistor so that your 3.3V logic is compatible. Then generate the +10V from 3.3V with a boost IC. Lots of other solutions but this is the cleanest, simplest I can think of. I can draw a schematic if this sounds like a good solution to you.

Comment: Oops, yes it is 2500pF not nF.  Also, the PWM pins are programmed to be synchronized exactly opposite of each other which results in -3.3v to 3.3v.  Not quite sure how it works, but found a Push-Pull code library, and it works very well.

Comment: @Curtis you can even skip the transformer if you get a piezo driver with integrated voltage boost converter from TI or Fairchild. Dual half-bridge with high-voltage boost all in one chip.

Comment: Do you know the model number of this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a 25KHz square wave through a 2:1 step-up transformer using a non-gapped core with little distortion if you are careful that the square wave has a duty cycle of exactly 50% and, if you use a push-pull winding on the primary, wind bifilar so that you have exactly the same number of turns.  Any lack of symmetry will result in the having a DC bias and the output will be distorted.  I often run a "D" flip flop divide-by-two on the driver circuit to make sure the waveform stays at 50%.

Comment: Without a dedicated driver, the transformer may result in excessive current draw between the I/O pins of the micro. There are convenient battery-spec dual half-bridges that could provide more drive, but still no amplitude calibration. The specifications of the transformer need a sufficient volt-time product to produce a square wave at 25kHz.

Comment: I'm going to use a 3:1 step up transformer and perhaps a couple Transisters to give me some amplitude.